# Validation for multiplying value at C++?

Tags: c++, validation

I have to make a test where a number has to be the **multiple** of 500,

```
      do{
            cout << "Input Price[price>0|price multiple of 500]: ";
            cin >> price;
            cin.sync(); cin.clear();
        } while (price<1 || price>5000);
```

The code is still incomplete, I just have to add the following validation left. What do I do?

and also what is the right term for that kind of validation? I had a hard time determining the title.

Comment: Are you looking for `(price % 500 == 0)` ?

Comment: i got unhandled exception instead when i put it on a bool function, and it's still with the same result when i used it as an argument for while

Comment: You must have done something wrong. Show the code that exhibits this undesirable behavior.

Comment: I just solved it myself , i was making an array of object, but i forgot to initialize some variable.

thx man!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your test :

```
price % 500 == 0
```

This is commonly called a [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (finds the remainder of the division between two numbers) : if your price is a multiple of 500, then the remainder of the division between price and 500 is 0.

Comment: i got unhandled exception instead when i put it on a bool function, and it's still with the same result when i used it as an argument for while

Comment: @RevanzaGotoku: `do{cin >> price;}while(price % 500 != 0);`